# Oracle weblogic performance

Tags: weblogic

We are planning to have production environment for our application, to plan the server we need following information

- how many users can login max to the application/server (sample data)
- what is the minimum memory required to run web application and Enterprise application
- how many max managed servers we can create

Answer (score 1):

Your questions are very broad to be answered in current form.

All of this ***depends*** on the hardware you use, how well-tuned it is, and how many transactions each user will be performing.

As a starting point you could look at the [Oracle guide on Weblogic server capacity planning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/perform/appc_capplan.html) which will give you an idea of the various factors affecting this.

We run Weblogic on 32 GB RAM servers, typically with 4 - 8 GB for each managed server, and can support 500 concurrent users or more depending on their active sessions.